# Организация поторяющихся полей в таблицах

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, ооп, любой-язык

В моей практикте часто встречаются проблемы отображения ООП подхода на реляционные базы данных в случае полей одинакового типа в одном классе. Не могу понять как решать такую проблему наиболее эффективным способом.

***Более подробный пример:***

У меня есть сущность `Person` у которой есть поля `address` и `workAddress`. Причем у обоих подсущностей одинаковый набор полей.

В коде это примерно так (псевдокод):

```
class Person 
  Address address
  Address workAddress
```

Как реализовывать это с помощью языков программирования понятно. Возникает вопрос как это сделать в БД. Я могу сделать, например, так (псевдо `sql`):

```
CREATE TABLE address (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE PERSON (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  address FOREIGN KEY (address.id), 
  workdAddress FOREIGN KEY (address.id)
);
```

Это будет работать, но это не совсем правильно с точки зрения теории БД. Ведь у нас будет один-ко-многим со стороны адрес-человек. Даже два раза.

Еще можно пойти таким способом:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE address_type (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE address (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  person_id FORIGN KEY(person.id),
  address_type FORIGN KEY (address_type.id)
);
```

Здесь мы получаем правильное решение с точки зрения реляционной модели, но из очень плохое решение для ООП. Из минусов тут: дополнительный `JOIN`, дополнительная таблича с типами, неудобно с этим работать в коде (надо перебрать все адреса для поиска нужного или дополнять селекты).

Искал решение в самом популярном `ORM` - `Hibernate`. Не нашел там ничего для решения такой проблемы (может плохо искал).

**Существуют ли какие-то общие практики, инструменты или механизмы для решения таких проблем?**

Comment: *Это будет работать, но это не совсем правильно с точки зрения теории БД. Ведь у нас будет один-ко-многим со стороны адрес-человек. Даже два раза.* Что тут неправильно? И почему? Всё тут правильно и логично - при условии, что моделируемый процесс допускает, что один и тот же адрес может быть и рабочим, и пропиской (у одной или разных персон - неважно). А если нет - то правильность структуры зависит от того, моделируется одна сущность "адрес" с атрибутом "прописка/работа", или две разные сущности (во втором случае должны быть две отдельные таблицы адресов).

Comment: @Akina Полностью согласен. Но есть непонятность с хранением уникальный адресов. Вопрос в том как мне узнавать уже существующие адреса. Делать селект, а потом апдейт или инсерт?

Comment: Проверка на существование адреса делается стандартно - запрос на поиск этого адреса. Если записей 0 - адрес новый, иначе нет. И возвращённый ИД используем.. увы, тут неразумен уникальный индекс по всему полю - большой, а хэш не гаантирует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял, что вопрос состоит в выборе:

1. Создать в целевой таблице несколько полей - ссылок на какой-то справочник
2. Создать дополнительную табличку, содержащую несколько записей, принадлежащих к одной записи целевой таблицы и ссылки на какой-то справочник (возможно с указанием типа связи и других параметров)

---

Оба варианта хорошие, имеют право на существование.
Какой из них выбрать зависит от требований к решаемой задаче.

Первый вариант можно выбрать в случае, если типы связи двух таблиц жестко фиксированы, не изменяются в процессе работы системы и не предусматривается их дальнейшее расширение. Также, этот вариант решения намного проще, чем второй.

Второй вариант можно выбрать в случае необходимости задания дополнительных параметров связи (тип, видимость, доступность, множественность, приоритетность) и в случае, если предусматривается гибкое управление типами связи этих двух таблиц. Например, теоретически возможно хранение истории изменений связанных данных.

---

В привязке к конкретной схеме адресов - для простоты вполне подходит первый вариант.
Если же вдруг понадобится хранить историю изменения адреса, то больше подходит второй. Или вдруг могут появиться дополнительные типы адресов - например адрес доставки, прописки, проживания, почтовый итп.

Answer (score 1):

> Это будет работать, но это не совсем правильно с точки зрения теории БД. Ведь у нас будет один-ко-многим со стороны адрес-человек. Даже два раза.

а вы уверены что у вас один-ко-многим? особенно с рабочим адресом? или вы намеренно дублируете данные из других соображений (безопасность, итд)

если же оснований для дублирования нет, то можно смоделировать это как многие-ко-многим используя класс ассоциации

```
create table Person (
    id serial primary key,
    name text
    -- etc
);
create table Address (
    id serial primary key,
    street text
    -- etc
);
create table PersonsAddresses (
    person_id foreign key (person.id),
    address_id foreign key (address.id),
    type int --or text or enum,
    primary key(person_id, address_id, type)
);
```

Comment: *а вы уверены что у вас один-ко-многим? особенно с рабочим адресом?* Сам понял что спросил? ясен пень, один и тот же адрес может быть у нескольких разных персон. И даже у одной персоны в обоих полях. Одному адресу соответствует несколько персон - это какая, по-твоему, связь?

Comment: вопрос был адресован утверждению автора "Ведь у нас будет один-ко-многим со стороны адрес-человек. Даже два раза." и то что в реальном мире связь персон с адресом многие ко многим это тоже "пень ясен" :) но не факт что этот "ясен пень" всегда должен быть отражен в модели.

Comment: Ааа... тогда, наверное, есть смысл это пояснить прямо в ответе - ну для снятия неоднозначностей... скажем, цитатой из вопроса.